# How to get financial info area in Google SERP?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I've noticed that some results in Google have additional snippets with a selection of financial information:

[image]

What's the name of this area? How to get this data to show up in the search results? Looking at the websites which have them, there doesn't seem to be any microdata or JSON-LD related to it. Is it extracted automatically by Google?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this specific example, the additional snippet text appears to be extracted automatically from the page. This often happens when Google re-writes meta descriptions because the ones they discover are lacking in specifics or relevance.

Comment: Any idea how to encourage this on your own page?